# Permission denied while importing PyV8

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, pyv8

```
>>> import PyV8
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/PyV8.py", line 33, in <module>
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_PyV8.py", line 7, in <module>
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_PyV8.py", line 3, in __bootstrap__
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2760, in <module> 
        add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 738, in 
        subscribe callback(dist)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2760, in <lambda> 
        add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2314, in activate 
        for pkg in self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt'):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2305, in _get_metadata 
        for line in self.get_metadata_lines(name):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1369, in get_metadata_lines
        return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1361, in get_metadata
        return self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info,name))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1470, in _get
        stream = open(path, 'rb')
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:  
        '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_apputils-0.4.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/namespace_packages.txt'
```

I had some problem while installing PyV8 as mentioned here - [error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127987/error-command-c-failed-with-exit-status-1) but solved that using http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1480282#post_11247864 . But now when I import, it says Permission Denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what are the permissions on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_apputils-0.4.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/namespace_packages.txt?

Comment: -rw-r----- 1 root staff 7 

I am having this problem with pip command also. I think I messed up something

Comment: is you user in group staff?

Comment: I ran command "groups amit"  OUTPUT - amit adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare - else I didn't understand your question

Comment: try this command and then retry the import sudo chmod o+r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_apputils-0.4.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/namespace_packages.txt